# How to put link and increment counter on same button in asp.net and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, counter, increment

web app in vs 2012 and SQL server
I want to have a counter increment and link to another website with one click 
please help me.

Comment: This question contains less information; could you please be more specific?

Comment: Any code which you have wrote or tired to achieve your goal? if yes then share with us. What supposed to be incremented, from where to redirect another website what is one click....all these will only be clear if you share your finding.